# Database name on AWS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I successfully created a MySQL database on AWS but I don't remember any field that demands database name when I was creating the database. Now I'm faced with an operation that is demanding for my database name. I checked my database instance but my database name column is blank. How do I resolve this?[image: No database name here]

Comment: What is the operation demanding the database name?  Can you at least connect to RDS from the command line, assuming that is how you are connecting?

Comment: I want to connect the database to my project and create new tables

Comment: Are you using the RDS GUI interface, or are you using the CLI?

Comment: No, I am running the script that will connect the database from my CMD. I am following a guide at https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80. I'm at step 4 of the guide.

Comment: You're going to have to connect to MySQL without specifying a database name.  Then, list all databases and find the actual name.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I got this error "(pymysql.err.InternalError) (1046, 'No database selected)"

Comment: I don't know what you tried.  Just get into your MySQL database by whatever means, and find your database name.